# Custom audio control for ios apps

Tags: swift, custom-controls, audio-player

We are creating an app using Swift on IOS that needs to use custom audio controls: a play button, a stop button, a current time/pos indicator, the duration and perhaps even a seek bar to play 1 audio file that is built into the application.  My friend has worked hard on this project but so far was unable to find a solution.  Is it possible using mediaplayer or is another api easier, possibly something similar to exoplayer for android apps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion I would say that using AVFoundation would probably be easiest since it is built into swift you just have to do `import AVFoundation` and you would probably want to create an AVAudioPlayer to listen to the music. Also the API is pretty simple. If you need any help getting started I found this article on Mashable that shows how to play audio and how to control it with a custom play and pause button. https://medium.com/yay-its-erica/creating-a-music-player-app-in-swift-3-53809471f663. Also I found on Apple's documentation how to get the current time of the audio playing https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer/1387297-currenttime. I hope I was able to help and if you have anymore questions don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: Is there a callback function I can use to update a seek bar control?